# Can I have less than 2.5TB of disk for a BigTable node?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-bigtable, bigtable

In the GCP user interface I can estimate the pricing for whatever disk size I wish to use, but when I want to create my BigTable instance I can only choose the number of nodes and each node comes with 2.5TB of SSD or HDD disk.

Is there a way to, for example, setup a BigTable cluster with 1 node and 1TB of SSD instead of the 2.5TB default one ?

Even in the GCP pricing calculator I can change the disk size, but I can't find where to configure it when creating the cluster (https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator#id=2acfedfc-4f5a-4a9a-a5d7-0470d7fa3973)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want a 1TB database, then only write 1TB and you'll be charged accordingly.

From the [Bigtable pricing documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/pricing):

> Cloud Bigtable frequently measures the average amount of data in your
>   Cloud Bigtable tables during a short time interval. For billing
>   purposes, these measurements are combined into an average over a
>   one-month period, and this average is multiplied by the monthly rate.
>
> **You are billed only for the storage you use**, including overhead for
>   indexing and Cloud Bigtable's internal representation on disk. For
>   instances that contain multiple clusters, Cloud Bigtable keeps a
>   separate copy of your data with every cluster, and you are charged for
>   every copy of your data.
>
> When you delete data from Cloud Bigtable, the data becomes
>   inaccessible immediately; however, you are charged for storage of the
>   data until Cloud Bigtable compacts the table. This process typically
>   takes up to a week.
>
> In addition, if you store multiple versions of a value in a table
>   cell, or if you have set an expiration time for one of your table's
>   column families, you can read the obsolete and expired values until
>   Cloud Bigtable completes garbage collection for the table. You are
>   also charged for the obsolete and expired values prior to garbage
>   collection. This process typically takes up to a week.

Comment: Thank you ! Must have missed it in the documentation, that's great :)